# jQuery hide on checkbox multiple values

Tags: jquery, checkbox, custom-data-attribute

I have 7 checkboxes with all a different ID. Those ID's correspondent with div's containing an data-methode in it. Clicking on a checkbox will hide all div's except for that one with the corresponding ID.

At this moment that works! But when I select multiple checkboxes all the divs disappear.

This is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery('.filter_methode input').change(function()
    {
        jQuery('.featured-item-container').show();
        jQuery('input').each(function()
            {
            var Checked;
            if(Checked = jQuery(this).attr('checked'))
                {
                    jQuery(".featured-item-container:not([data-methode='" + this.id + "'])").hide();
                };
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

I wonder how I can optimize this script so it listens to all selected ID's.

**Edit**
Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="filter_methode">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="methode_1"  id="methode_1" />
Methode 1</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="methode_2" id="methode_2"  />
Methode 2</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="methode_3" id="methode_3"  />
Methode 3</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="methode_4" id="methode_4" />
Methode 4</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="methode_5" id="methode_5" />
Methode 5</label>


<label><input type="checkbox" name="methode_6" id="methode_6" />
Methode 6</label>


<label><input type="checkbox" name="methode_7" id="methode_7" />
Methode 7</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="methode_8" id="methode_8" />
Methode 8</label>
```

```
<div class="featured-container col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_1">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_1">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_1">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_3">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_7">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_8">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_2">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_4">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_8">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_5">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_6">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_5">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_1">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
        <div class="featured-item-container" data-methode="methode_2">
            Some text and image in here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I click checkbox with ID methode_1 it does show me only the divs with data-methode="methode_1", but when I also click on checkbox methode_2 all divs disappear instead of showing me the divs with methode_1 and methode_2

Comment: Show your html code.

Comment: Shouldn't `if(Checked = jQuery(this).attr('checked'))` be `==` as in `if(Checked == jQuery(this).attr('checked'))`? Also, good if you post the `html` too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I have the code here is the solution:

```
jQuery('.filter_methode input').change(function()
    {
        jQuery('.featured-item-container').hide();
        jQuery('input').each(function(k,v)
            { 
            var Checked = $(v).prop( "checked" );
            if(Checked)
                { 
                    jQuery(".featured-item-container[data-methode='" + v.id + "']").show();
                };
        }); 
        if(jQuery('input:checked').length == 0) {
            jQuery('.featured-item-container').show();
        }
    });
```

there is no "this" in an anonymous function. You can access the object with the second parameter.

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/92u6u72L/3/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this does not work for me. When I click a checkbox now all the divs disappear instead of only the ones I didn't check.

Comment: Thanks @aleksv this does work indeed! However, when I uncheck those boxes now it does hide all items. Is there any way to make a check on that?

Comment: That did the trick thanks! Similar to this question, maybe you could also take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461933/update-wp-query-with-ajax-form-checkbox?noredirect=1#comment62432008_37461933